# Jackson ObjectMapper CUSTOM global filter usage

Tags: java, jackson

My use case is as follows:

I want to globally remove all empty strings and null values from serialization, this is easily achieved by using: `this.objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`. However, I don't want this to be applied to empty lists (i.e. empty lists must remain). In this use case I do not and cannot have a POJO for the JSON data that I am working with so I must have the configuration on the object mapper.

I tried using `this.objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM)`, but unlike `@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = SomeFilter.class)` annotation, the `setSerializationInclusion` doesn't take another argument for me to specify a filter class...

I have also tried

```
this.objectMapper.configOverride(Collection.class).setInclude(Value.construct(Include.ALWAYS, Include.ALWAYS));
```

However have not had much luck, is there a way to achieve this using the `ObjectMapper` config as opposed to class annotations in Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this annotation by default via `setDefaultPropertyInclusion`. Here is my approach:

```
ObjectMapper regularMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .setDefaultPropertyInclusion(new JsonInclude.Value(Dummy.class.getAnnotation(JsonInclude.class)));
```

And `Dummy` has following signature

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Filter.class)
private static class Dummy {}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, this works fine in the sense that I can supply a filter class... However, the issue with this solution is it only works on the first depth of my JSON data. For instance, it will only scan the top level map and not apply the filter on nested objects. Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how I can truly filter using options on the `ObjectMapper` itself, but found a slightly different solution using modules. My usecase is that I don't want to use `Include.NON_EMPTY` because it omits empty lists in serialization which I'd like to keep, I only want to remove fields with value `null` and `""` from my data.

A simple serializer is good enough to filter empty string fields and apply something onto them, in my approach I set all fields with empty string values to `null`:

```java
public class EmptyStringSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {

  public EmptyStringSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public EmptyStringSerializer(Class<String> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      jgen.writeString(value);
    } else {
      jgen.writeNull();
    }
  }
}
```

Now to attach it to the object mapper...

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(String.class, new EmptyStringSerializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

This means that all String fields will be evaluated upon serialization, now it's easy enough to clean up by using: `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);` - Which will remove all fields with `null` values in the dataset.

This is not an ideal solution, and there must be a more convenient way to apply a filter by using the `Include.CUSTOM` inclusion but it seems very complicated. Even from geobreze's answer, it's quite peculiar that one needs to proxy a POJO in order to apply a `valueFilter`...